# Change Lightswitch grid column header title at runtime

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

In my lightswitch app I have a datagrid. How can I change the column header title of certain columns at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/8a5cb410-82f4-472c-8c33-13afd52acb6c)....thanks to the Lightswitch forums